# Segmenting dark spots from a light background?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, edge-detection

I need to perform automatic segmentation of dark blue spots on light yellow paper. Here's a very simple example:

[image: Simple example]

In this case, a simple threshold based on hue or brightness works well. But here are some more challenging real-world examples:

[image: Hard 1]
[image: Hard 2]

Clearly a simple hue/brightness threshold will fail when dealing with shadows, exposure issues, and small stains where the color is blurred from the background.

I've tried Otsu's method for adaptive thresholding, but it also fails to account for shadows - and produces erratic results when analyzing "blank" cards.

Is there a form of localized thresholding that might work better? I've also considered edge detection, but am unsure how to transform the results into the needed binary image. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: For the shadow pattern... If you deal with only shadowed region, can you find good threshold to binalize the region?
If yes, when binalized result has big black regions(shadowed region), you can extract such regions and reprocess only them, I think.

Comment: "when dealing with..." defects caused by humans that haven't been instructed to take good pictures. whatever technical measures to you consider to repair the mess, please also instruct your humans to take good pictures.

Comment: try locally adaptive thresholds. or estimate local brightness in some way (blur) and divide by that to get this normalized. you will always have to expect artefacts around the edges of hard shadows. -- since your features of interest can be discriminated by color, which is invariant to lighting changes, you should just try a suitable color space and see if you can ignore brightness entirely.

Comment: Otsu is not an adaptive method.